# Our website was overloaded, how to solve it?

Tags: load-balancing

We developed a website, and recently we found that our website was overloaded:

1. One single server can not process all requests effectively.
2. Our database can not save all the data, and the connection is usually not enough.
3. Our network bandwidth is not enough for all request.

I want to know how can we solve these problems ? What is the popular ways of solving these ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't see, where this is related to c#, java and php! Beside that it belongs to ServerFault.com IMHO

Comment: The answers to the second part of q2 and q3 of are easy enough: upgrade your connections. I also wonder if the answer to q1 is caused by db overload or the webserver itself is groaning?

Comment: These are 3 different problems it seems. Adding servers can be a solution for 1 and 2 but if the problem comes from the application architecture then you are just relaying the issue to the future. For 3 buy more bandwith and/or reduce the number of requests needed per user.

Comment: if i can easy add a server ,then it's not a problem ...

Comment: Do you have a url I could analyse the performance and bandwidth requirments of?

Comment: Although it's arguable that if the cost of development is more than the cost of additional hardware then it's better to add servers.

Comment: No, it can only be used by staffs, I heard of load balancing, is this a solution ?

Comment: Before you do anything you need to determine what load your systems CAN handle. Then determine what they NEED to handle. Unless you can answer both those questions properly you can be sure you'll be throwing a lot more money at this than is necessary. Decisions made in a vacuum are worthless. The exact same thing applies to code optimization. The lack of sufficient and appropriate information is what causes the costs to blow out, not the actual optimization.

Comment: Hooligan - post a diagram and/or a good explanation of the architecture. Is this all on a single server, or do you have one server for web and one for DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few dead-tree recommendations to help you in the long run:

- [High Performance Web Sites](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596529309) by Steve Souders
- [Even Faster Web Sites](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596522304) by Steve Souders
- [Scalable Internet Architectures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/067232699X) by Theo Schlossnagle
- [The Art of Capacity Planning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596518579) by John Allspaw

There are several websites that outline Steve's performance guidelines that you can easily find through a Google search.  Most of them will help reduce the number of requests and speed up the remaining ones.  Theo's book, however, is invaluable in regards to building out scalable systems and I highly recommend giving it a read.  John's book is a quick read but will give you insight into how to plan for future expansion.

Answer (score 3):

- Get a faster computer for frontend
- Get a faster computer for the database
- Get a faster network connection

Yeah, all of those cost money. But probably less money that going through all your code to optimize it, unless you have a some massive inefficiencies that are easy to pinpoint. But if everything (web server, DB and network) is overloaded, it doesn't sound like it.

Comment: On the flip side, almost everyone has some massive inefficiencies hiding somewhere :)

Comment: if i can easy add a server ,then it's not a problem

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible to reduce your bandwidth requirements and reduce your server load by reducing HTTP Requests by a number of simple performance tweaks. Setting far-future expiration dates on static content, combining files like css sprites, combining javascript and css. You could also do with outsourcing jQuery and other Javascript libraries to Google using their free Google AJAX Libraries API.